# OAuth in microsoft sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get the access token from microsoft sharepoint but I could not find any useful docs to achieve this.

Could you please guide me how to do oauth in microsoft share point?

Please explain steps like
how to create an app, getting client id and client secret and url and its parameters to do the oauth.

Thanks